# extract specific data from HTML -CDATA- pattern in C#

Tags: c#, html, xml, string

I have problem while parsing data from XML Feed, The description node contains this line :

```
<![CDATA[<div><b>ID:</b> 40</div><div><b>Name:</b> John</div>]]>
```

How can i parse the ID & Name with values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using HtmlAgilityPAck and Regex as fallows:

```js
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
string a = "<![CDATA[<div><b>ID:</b> 40</div><div><b>Name:</b> John</div>]]>";
doc.LoadHtml(Regex.Match(Regex.Match(a, @"\[([^)]*)\]").Groups[1].Value, @"\[([^)]*)\]").Groups[1].Value);
var divs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div");
string ID = divs[0].InnerText.Split(':')[1];
string Name = divs[1].InnerText.Split(':')[1];
```

this works for me with your data example